# how to take care mutiply condition check in Common lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Just learning Common Lisp for a few days, but Professor had assigned an exercise for me. However, my code is not able to compile, Can anyone show me where I did wrong with my coding part?[image: This is the question]

```
(defun( MIN-2 a b)
(cond  
((and (numberp a) (numberp b) (<= a b)) a b)
((and (numberp a) (numberp b)    nil) ERROR)
)
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Literal translation:

```
(defun min-2 (a b)  ; Define a Lisp function MIN-2 … takes two arguments A and B
  (cond ((and (every #'numberp (list a b)) (<= a b)) a)  ; if … A <= B, returns A
        ((and (every #'numberp (list a b)) (> a b)) b)   ; if … A > B, returns B
        (t 'error)      ; if A or B is not a number (i. e. “else”), returns ERROR
```

Improvement: check for numbers just once beforehand.

```
(defun min-2 (a b)
  (cond ((not (every #'numberp (list a b))) 'error)
        ((<= a b) a)
        ((> a b) b)))
```

And please indent your code and don't leave the parentheses lying around.

Comment: How good is your Lisp compiler at eliminating that `(list a b)` consing?

Comment: @Kaz: `(and (numberp a) (numberp b))` looks smaller in the disassembly.  If you need the performance, use that.

Comment: can you explain to me what is ' before numberp, why we need ' ? Thank You.

Comment: @hello: `#'numberp` means `(function numberp)` which means “the function object named numberp”.  We want to pass that function as a parameter to the higher order function `every`.  If we wrote just `numberp`, it would mean “the value bound to the variable numberp”, which is a different, unrelated thing.

Answer (score 1):

### Why your code fails

> Can anyone show me where I did wrong with my coding part?

```
(defun( MIN-2 a b)
(cond  
((and (numberp a) (numberp b) (<= a b)) a b)
((and (numberp a) (numberp b)    nil) ERROR)
)
)
```

Let me reformat your code (auto-indent + compress parentheses):

```
(defun (MIN-2 a b) ;; << bad syntax, as already pointed out in another answer
    (cond  
      ((and (numberp a) (numberp b) (<= a b))
       a
       b)

      ((and (numberp a) (numberp b) nil)
       ERROR)))
```

Let's fix the syntax of `defun`:

```
(defun MIN-2 (a b)
    (cond  
      ((and (numberp a) (numberp b) (<= a b))
       a
       b)

      ((and (numberp a) (numberp b) nil)
       ERROR)))
```

Error (I am compiling the code under Emacs + SBCL):

> Undefined variable: ERROR

Indeed, `error` is a free variable here. You need to quote it.

```
(defun MIN-2 (a b)
    (cond  
      ((and (numberp a) (numberp b) (<= a b))
       a
       b)

      ((and (numberp a) (numberp b))
       'ERROR)))
```

Warning:

> Deleting unreachable code *(ERROR is underlined)*.

Indeed, the condition here is a `and` expression where at least one of the
expression is `NIL`, which means the conjunction is always false. The case can never happen, which is why the was optimized away.

Also, the first clause's test is:

```
(and (numberp a) (numberp b) (<= a b))
```

And the clause body is `a` followed by `b`, which means `a` is evaluated, its value discarded (it is never used), then `b` is evaluated and its value is the  value of the `cond` expression: you always return `b` when both inputs are numbers such that `a <= b`.

Clearly, this is not what you should do. Other answers already covered good solutions.

### Alternatives

I am also here to offer alternative, not necessarily homework-friendly answers:

#### Catch exceptions

```
(defun min-2 (a b)
  (handler-case (if (<= a b) a b)
    (error () 'error)))
```

#### Catch exceptions (bis)

```
(defun min-2 (a b)
  (or (ignore-errors (if (<= a b) a b))
      'error))
```

#### Use generic functions

```
(defgeneric min-2 (a b)
  (:method ((a number) (b number)) (if (<= a b) a b))
  (:method (a b) 'error))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong syntax for defining a function. Use `defun function-name (args)`

```
(defun MIN-2 (a b)
(cond  
((and (numberp a) (numberp b) (<= a b)) a b)
((and (numberp a) (numberp b)    nil) ERROR)
)
)
```

Comment: In Common Lisp, you can have as many forms in a `cond` clause as you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's worth writing functions like this in a way which makes clear what is the sanity check and what is the actual computation.  So in this case the sanity check is: 'are both arguments numbers?' and the computation is the comparison of them if they are.  So separate these two things rather than bundling it all into one conditional:

```
(defun min-2 (a b)
  (if (and (numberp a) (numberp b))
      ;; sanity check OK, so compare them
      (if (<= a b)
          a
        b)
    'error))
```

Unfortunately, of course, the sanity check is not adequate:

```
> (min-2 1 2)
1

> (min-2 1 'a)
error

> (min-2 1 #c(1 1))

Error: In <= of (1 #C(1 1)) arguments should be of type real.
```

Oops: what the sanity check *should* be is whether the two arguments are *real* numbers.  Fortunately, there's a predicate for that, which is `realp`.  So a correct version of `min-2` is:

```
(defun min-2 (a b)
  (if (and (realp a) (realp b))
      ;; sanity check OK, so compare them
      (if (<= a b)
          a
        b)
    'error))
```